# Segment customers bigquery / SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following datas and I would like to know the position of the order at the date value for the 12 previous months. For example if it was the first, the second, the third... order of the customer during the 12 previous months… impossible to succeed in :( Someone can help me ?

[datas to segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPgrM.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to see whether an order was the 1st, 2nd, 3rd..and so on for each of your customers.

If so, a window function like row_number will work nicely.

```
select 
date_date as Date,
customers_id,
orders_id,
CA_ht
row_number() over (partition by customers_id order by date_date asc) as order_position
from Data
```

Example below using mock data.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
  `Customer_ID` VARCHAR(5),
  `Order_date` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Data
  (`Customer_ID`, `Order_date`)
VALUES
  ('ID001', '11/04/2022'),
  ('ID001', '14/03/2022'),
  ('ID001', '17/03/2022'),
  ('ID001', '21/03/2022'),
  ('ID001', '16/03/2022'),
  ('ID002', '16/03/2022'),
  ('ID002', '26/03/2022'),
  ('ID002', '21/03/2022'),
  ('ID002', '01/04/2022'),
  ('ID002', '13/03/2022'),
  ('ID001', '19/03/2022'),
  ('ID001', '07/04/2022'),
  ('ID002', '01/04/2022');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select *,row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by Order_Date asc) as order_position
from Data;
```

| Customer_ID | Order_date | order_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | 07/04/2022 | 1 |
| ID001 | 11/04/2022 | 2 |
| ID001 | 14/03/2022 | 3 |
| ID001 | 16/03/2022 | 4 |
| ID001 | 17/03/2022 | 5 |
| ID001 | 19/03/2022 | 6 |
| ID001 | 21/03/2022 | 7 |
| ID002 | 01/04/2022 | 1 |
| ID002 | 01/04/2022 | 2 |
| ID002 | 13/03/2022 | 3 |
| ID002 | 16/03/2022 | 4 |
| ID002 | 21/03/2022 | 5 |
| ID002 | 26/03/2022 | 6 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

You can swap out row_number for rank or dense_rank, more details on these can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions). The benefit of using dense_rank or rank depends on if it's possible for your customers to order multiple times in one day, and how to want to handle those ties.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes this is the idea thank you. The constraint here is that the period of 12 months is rolling, that means that for a order made on the 01/01/22 it will not be compatibilized on the 02/01/23 any more. Like for a loyalty program. I should remove from the total the orders that are older than 12 months.